# Does deleting an original asset but keeping the transform folder asset make Craft replace the original file with the biggest transform?

Tags: craft3, assets, image-transforms

I have a client who has uploaded many giant images to the CMS (8mb+). I'd like to free up that space now that those image have been transformed to more web-friendly sizes. Is it safe for me to delete the original files stored on the server or does Craft require those to create new transforms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does deleting an original asset but keeping the transform folder asset make Craft replace the original file with the biggest transform?

No - Craft will always use the originally uploaded asset as the "source of truth" for generating new transforms.

You can, however, replace the originally uploaded 8mb+ file with a smaller one, and it'll be used as the source of truth for generating new transforms.

Comment: Thanks Brad! A bit outside the scope of this forum's focus but is there a batch image downsizer you could recommend?

Comment: The last time I tried anything like that, I automated it in Photoshop.